# Issues with Php Music File Uploader

Tags: php

So I'm trying to upload music files with php but the files aren't going to the folder, here's my code what are my mistakes and what am i missing

```
        <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="File Name" name="file_name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Artist Name" name="artist_name">
    <textarea rows="5" placeholder="Description" name="description"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning bgcolor" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
    </form>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){            
    function GetMusicExtension($musictype)
         {
           if(empty($musictype)) return false;
           switch($musictype){
               case 'audio/mp3': return '.mp3';
               default: return false;
           }
        }

        if (!empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {

            $file_name=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
            $temp_name=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
            $music_type=$_FILES["file"]["type"];
            $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
            $ext= GetMusicExtension($music_type);
            $musicname = $_POST['file_name'].$ext;              
            $target_path = "music/".$musicname;


        if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {                              
            $query = "insert into music(name,artist,description) 
            values('".$musicname."','".$_POST['artist_name']."','".$_POST['description']."')";              
            mysqli_query($link,$query) or die("error in $query == ----> ".mysqli_error($link));                                                 
            }   
        }else{

           exit('<script>alert("Error Saving Data... try again");</script>');
        }
    }                   
    ?>
```

PS: If i change the mime to an image mime and try uploading it uploads

**UPDATE:**
If i change post_max_size and upload_max_size it works. Thanks all.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: @mrunion I don't get any error nothing just happens

Comment: Then have you checked to make sure the mp3 files are not larger than allowed in your php.ini file? Have you debugged/traced/echo'd out your variables after the "if(!empty...) line? Is there anything there?

Comment: it doesn't exceed the limit and I tried print_r($_FILES); nothing displayed.

Comment: @Rhyno_xD - Sounds like a permissions issue. Add this to the top of your file and you should see what the error is: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: @Adelphia I just did that no errors.